# Smarty not rendering fast enough for Facebook Scraper to find meta tags

Tags: php, facebook, smarty

I use the smarty template engine and I have placed some Facebook meta tags on my site. It appears that Facebook's **scraper** is faster than the rendering smarty rendering engine.

Here is a link to the LINT tool's output:
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fslipdragon.com%2Fvideo%2F6XA881OYRRHB%2FBmx-Street-Video--Vasya-L--Carhartt-Team](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://slipdragon.com/video/6XA881OYRRHB/Bmx-Street-Video--Vasya-L--Carhartt-Team)

In my template I drawing the meta tags from variables assigned by the template engine:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{$vdo.title|strip_tags|strip}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{$vdo.description|strip_tags|strip}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://slipdragon.com{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}" />
```

Any ideas how to set this up? It appears that smarty rendering of the template is too slow for Facebook's **scraper** . According to the LINT tool Facebook isn't evening seeing a og:title or any other meta tag properly populated.

Comment: Hmm, I think something else is wrong. Are you positive the page is rendering properly when you visit in your browser with exactly same URL as Facebook.

Comment: If you compare the source of Facebooks LINT tool with the actual page source you will see that the actual page source shows the meta tags properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was authentication. Facebook's LINT tool is not able to correctly parse the page because it is behind login credentials. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

activate [debugging](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.debugging.tpl) and see how long the actual rendering of the template took. Unless you're doing some really funky things or screwed up badly - Smarty is not causing the delay. It's much more likely that some of your database queries, external resource lookups, etc. are the cause.

Comment: Rodney thanks for the response. Does the template engine actually piece the page together in an async fashion? I am running a few queries.

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous about PHP. There is only one "thread". you can either push in your data up front (using `assign()`), or have it *pulled in* (by plugin functions).

Comment: Smarty caches your templates and turns them into PHP pages that are executes the next time.  Even if what you say is correct, the Meta tags are in the `HEAD` section so they would be rendered first.  Your barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your url.

The values are blank, its got nothing to do with speed, Smarty tags are blank when they dont exist.

Somehow

```
{$vdo.title|strip_tags|strip}
{$vdo.description|strip_tags|strip}
```

dont exist, please try locally and get the values in before involving facebook.